# Wordpress Issue - Unable to edit posts

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Worpress, had set it all up on 1and1 server, everything was going fine, then the "Edit Posts" in Dashboard stopped working.  Now I can no longer access my posts to edit, I just get a blank page.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, 1and1 requires these php5 mapping rules at the top of your .htaccess file. It's a common question/problem in the wordpress.org forums.

Add with a plain text editor:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have read write permissions setup propperly